# Including camel-test-spring causes NoClassDefFoundError for DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Camel project using Maven to build and manage dependencies. My project depends on Camel component versions 2.14.0. I've matched Spring dependencies with Camel and use Spring component versions 3.2.11.RELEASE. However, if I include camel-test-spring version 2.14.0 as a dependency in the test scope it pulls in both spring-beans version 4.0.7.RELEASE and spring-expression 4.0.7.RELEASE into the runtime scope, which result is my application throwing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer`. Oh, btw, the application boots from a Java main method with `org.apache.camel.spring.Main`.

Adding exclusions for both spring-beans and spring-expression into the POM dependency for camel-test-spring resolves the runtime exception but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do. Does anyone have more insight into why camel-test-spring 2.14.0 depends on the 4.0.7.RELEASE versions of spring-beans and spring-expression when most (all?) the other Camel 2.14.0 components seem to depend on 3.2.11.RELEASE versions of Spring components?

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please you camel-test-spring3 which support Spring 3.x instead of camel-test-spring (for Spring 4.0.x).